# Uma função definida dentro de uma função recursiva é ruim?

Tags: javascript

Olá. Eu tinha em javascript um código mais ou menos assim:

```
function loop (i) {
    function callback () {
        // fazia alguma coisa
        if (i < 10) loop(++i);
    }
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

Basicamente uma função que é chamada pelo `setTimeout` e que está definida dentro de uma função que ela vai chamar de novo. Há algum problema de desempenho nisso? Em python ou outra linguagem isso também é ruim?

Comment: Qual seria o objeto desta função? Uma função interna que utiliza o escopo de sua função mãe chamamos de closure. Para definir se isso deve ser feito ou não, é necessário descrever qual o objetivo da função; depende do "alguma coisa" dentro dela.

Answer (score 0):

Não há problema nenhum nisso e nem nenhum custo de desempenho. Inclusive essa prática é utilizada em diversos frameworks, tais como o jQuery.

Entretanto, tal como em qualquer outra coisa relacionada a programação, dependendo do caso, essa pode ou não ser a melhor abordagem. Em muitos casos onde o `setTimeout` é utilizado (mas não em todos), pode ser interessante utilizar-se [funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas). Novamente, isso daí é uma ferramenta que o desenvolvedor dispõe para utilizar, e como qualquer outra ferramenta, tem ocasiões onde é uma boa alternativa a se utilizar e ocasiões onde não é. Por exemplo, um martelo pode ser uma excelente ferramenta para afixar pregos, mas terá um péssimo resultado se o que você precisa é cortar um pedaço de madeira.

O uso de funções dentro de funções (muitas vezes anônimas) é um recurso muito utilizado em diversas linguagens de programação sobre o nome de [**lambda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

O python é uma linguagem que [implementa lambdas](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). O Java 8 e superior também (embora fosse possível e comum simular-se isso com classes anônimas desde o Java 1.1). O C# também implementa esse conceito. O JavaScript implementa desde o seu nascimento. O Pascal também conta com isso. Esse conceito é algo bastante difundido, embora seja algo que tenha sido negligenciado por muito tempo em diversas linguagens de programação, inclusive em algumas que já adotavam desde o começo, e só começou a ser valorizado a partir da década de 2000.

Algumas linguagens adotaram isso bem tardiamente, como por exemplo o C++, que [só implementou lambdas a partir da versão de 2011](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), embora ponteiros para funções estivessem sendo usados para fazer isso desde as primeiras versões do C (entretanto, sem permitir colocar uma função dentro da outra e com uma sintaxe horrorosa e muito desencorajadora).

Quanto a diferença de desempenho, obviamente isso depende da linguagem, mas em quase todas elas essa diferença, quando existe, é tão pequena que nem chega a ser mensurável.